# why the grayscale image has 3 channels

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

i am performing operations on a grayscale image, and the resultant image of these operations has the same extension as the input image. for an example if the input image is `.jpg` or `.png` the output image is either `.jpg` or `.png` respectively.

and I am converting the image into grayscale as follows:

```
ImgProc.cvtColor(mat, grayscale, ImgProc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),
```

and I am checking the channels count using:

```
.channels()
```

the problem is when I wnat to know how many channels the image contain, despit it is a grayscale image, i always receive umber of channels = 3!!

kindly please let me know why that is happening

Comment: How are you checking the channel count? If your doing it via imread are you specifying CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE? by default you will get BGR

Comment: @AlexK. please see my updates above

Comment: Why don't you try `ImgProc.cvtColor(mat, grayscale, ImgProc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY,1)`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic please tell me , why there is 1 as last parameter in your code?

Comment: Because that's the parameter that determines the number of channels in the output.

Comment: @RealSkeptic doe sthe type of the Mat could has any influence, I mean if the mat is of type CV_32F or CV_16U. and please let me know what these types mean?

Answer (score 2):

The depth (or better color depth) is the number of bits used to represent a color value.  a color depth of 8 usually means 8-bits per channel (so you have 256 color values - or better: shades of grey- per channel - from 0 to 255) and 3 channels mean then one pixel value is composed of 3*8=24 bits.

However, this also depends on nomenclature. Usually you will say

"Color depth is 8-bits per channel"

but you also could say

"The color depth of the image is 32-bits"

and then mean 8 bits per RGBA channel or

"The image has a color depth of 24-bits"

and mean 8-bits per R,G and B channels.

Comment: thanks for your answer. and i ahave a question please, when i display the type of the Mat object , i receive 5, and I checked the docs and i found that 5 could mean CV_16SC4 !! from here: http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.4/index.html?index-all.html   i am understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The grayscale image has three channels because technically it is **not a grayscale** image. It is a colored image with the **same values** for all the three channels (r, g, b) in every pixel. Therefore, visually it looks like a grayscale image.

To check the channels in the image, use-

**img.getbands()**