# Devanagari character recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to build a cnn model for my devanagari character recognition project. Everything is working fine except it show error at validation_data=valid_generator. It displays error like:

```
UnimplementedError:  Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.
```

My code is as follows:

```
from keras.utils import plot_model 
model.compile(
optimizer='adam', 
loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics=['accuracy']) 
data_gen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

data_gen_valid = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

train_generator = data_gen_train.flow_from_directory(directory="./train2", target_size=(32,32), 
batch_size=32, class_mode="binary")

valid_generator = data_gen_valid.flow_from_directory(directory="./valid2", target_size=(32,32), 
batch_size=32, class_mode="binary")

model.fit(
train_generator,
epochs = 3, 
steps_per_epoch=150,
validation_steps=150,
validation_data=valid_generator)
```

Comment: Can you share the entire Model Architecture and the entire reproducible code so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Following is my model architecture-
 
inputs = Input(shape=(32,32,1))
x = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu')(inputs)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Conv2D(filters = 32,        
kernel_size = 3,            
activation = 'relu')(x)  
x = MaxPooling2D()(x) 
x = Flatten()(x) 
x=Dense(256,
activation='relu')(x)
outputs = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(x) 
 
    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs) 
 
    model.summary()

Comment: Still couldn't reproduce your error. Can you share the complete reproducible code and the Tensorflow Version you are using. Thanks!

Comment: Sir, I am using black and white images for character recognition of size 32x32. So,as in my above comment my `inputs=Input(shape=(32,32,1))`. Actually I don't know  what no of channels should I give in output dense layer. As mentioned above, I wrote it as-`outputs=Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")`. So, after this my problem arose. But when I changed input shape as (32,32,3) which I should not use because I am not using coloured images. But now the code worked. So, tell me for black and white images what no of channels should be in ouput layer?@TensorflowWarriors

Comment: Good to know that your issue is resolved.

First thing to clarify is the Number of Channels we specify is for `Input Layer`, not `Output Layer`. Second thing is, sometimes, a Black and White Image can contain 3 Channels. Please refer this issue for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481593/why-the-grayscale-image-has-3-channels.

So, in your case, your Image has 3 Channels, even though it is a Black and White Image. 

This error is faced by many people in the community, so, it will be helpful to the community if you accept this Answer. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors Followed by my above code, I wrote code below for testing an image. `def prediction(x): 

  switcher = { 
      0:'ka', 
      1:'kha',
  }

  return switcher.get(x) 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
#Image to predict to out model 
img = cv2.imread(r"./drive/My Drive/test_dataset/characters/31050.png",0) 
plt.imshow(img) `

Comment: And further the following code-`img = np.expand_dims(img, axis= 0) 
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis = -1) 
pred = model.predict(img) 
print("The predicted character is:", prediction(np.argmax(pred))) `  The error displayed like this-` ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 32, 32, 1]`@TensorflowWarriors

Comment: Updated the Answer with Input `Image Pre-Processing`.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the Solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments Section, for the benefit of the Community.

The `Error`,

```
UnimplementedError:  Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.
```

arises if we pass the `Number of Channels` as 1 when the `Image` actually contains 3 Channels.
UnimplementedError:  Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.

The problem is resolved by changing the Number of Channels from 1 to 3 i.e., by changing the code from

```
inputs=Input(shape=(32,32,1))
```

to

```
inputs=Input(shape=(32,32,3))
```

**Edit**: Adding the Pre_Processing of `Image` during `Predictions`.

In order to predict on a New Image, please use the code mentioned below:

```
IMG_SIZE = 32
image = cv2.imread('ImageFileName.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
image = new_array / 255
image = image.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!